# NodeJS how to call a function returning a string from another folder

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, string, function

I want to call a function that returning a string from another folder.
The file structure is a follows:

- controllers folder - infoController.js file
- template folder - infoString.js file

infoString.js file code:

```
   module.exports = {

    infoHtml: function() {
        let html =
       `<body>
        <h1>$Info</h1>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Details:</td>
            <td>${productID}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
        `
        return html;
       }
    }
```

I tried to call the function in infoString.js in infoController.js file as follows:

```
htmlInfo = require("../template/infoString")
const productID = 114455;
let htmlInfoTemplate = htmlInfo.infoHtml();
console.log("HTML Info Template", htmlInfoTemplate); // Does not return the html string from infoHtml function
```

But it is not working somehow. May I have your opinions on this? Is there something Im missing here?

Comment: Hi Artimus.. What exactly isn't working? you seeing any error or some wrong output is being shown?

Comment: It is not returning the html string.

Comment: can you check the browser console or wherever you're running this if there's any error? For eg: is productID defined?

Comment: you define it as function not string

Comment: There are no error being return, just that the process is stucked on calling the function. productID is defined inside infoController. The idea is that I just want it to call it inside the infoController and used the variables defined in it.

Comment: then return it as object, example `module.exports = { value: "some value", html: "<...>"}` then call it `const fileParams = require("../template/yourfile"); console.log(fileParams.html);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much guys for the reply. But I have found the problem. The function does not work because I do not pass the variables information in the function, so what I have to do in infoString.js file code is to add productID variable.

```
   module.exports = {

    infoHtml: function(productID) {
        let html =
       `<body>
        <h1>$Info</h1>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Details:</td>
            <td>${productID}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
        `
        return html;
       }
    }
```

Then in the controller file, I will just need to also define and pass the variable.

```
htmlInfo = require("../template/infoString")
const productID = 114455;
let htmlInfoTemplate = htmlInfo.infoHtml(productID);
console.log("HTML Info Template", htmlInfoTemplate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this. I did not test this. but the error is in htmlInfo = require("../template/infoString")

module.exports = {
infoHtml: () => {
return '`<body> <h1>$Info</h1> <table> <tr> <td>Product Details:</td> <td>${productID}</td> </tr> </table> </body>` ';
},
};

assign the functions and values we want to export to an exports property on module:

const { infoHtml } = require('./user');
console.log(
`${infoHtml()}`
);